# What does *variable.shape mean in python

Tags: python, pytorch

I know `"*variable_name"` assists in packing and unpacking.

But how does *variable_name.shape work? Unable to visualize why the second dimension is squeezed out when prefixing with "*"?

```
print("top_class.shape {}".format(top_class.shape))
top_class.shape torch.Size([64, 1])

print("*top_class.shape {}".format(*top_class.shape))
*top_class.shape 64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `numpy.array` that is extensively used in math-related and image processing programs, `.shape` describes the size of the array for all existing dimensions:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((3,3,3))
>>> a
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
>>> a.shape
(3, 3, 3)
>>>
```

---

The asterisk "unpacks" the tuple into several separate arguments, in your case `(64,1)` becomes `64, 1`, so only the first one get printed because there's only one format specification.

Comment: But what about the asterix in front? What does that do/

Comment: @Khanna111 sorry, missed that part. the asterisk "unpacks" the tuple into several separate arguments, in your case `(64,1)` becomes `64, 1`, so only the first one get printed because there's only one format specification

Comment: Where can I get access to this "formal specification" so I know where to look next time?
In the first print it prints 64,1 but not in this case and hence the confustion

Comment: @Khanna111 you may change `"*top_class.shape {}"` into `"*top_class.shape {} {}"` and see what happens =)